# Display products under category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code to show products under category in the shop page:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'seperate_collection', 10);
function seperate_collection(){
    // men's collections
    if ( is_shop() ){
        $cat_args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'parent' => 42 // for-him category id.
        );
        $categories = get_categories( $cat_args );
        foreach ($categories as $category) { 
            echo '<h3>' . $category->cat_name . '</h3>';
            echo do_shortcode('[products category="' . $category->slug . '" columns="4" orderby="date" order="DESC"]'); 
        }

    }

}
```

It does exactly what I want.

But my problem is that the products show up again after the listed categories.
I tried to use the following code to hide the products from showing again:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_products_from_shop_page' );

function remove_products_from_shop_page( $q ) {
   if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
   if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;
   if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {
      $q->set( 'post__in', array(0) );
   }
   remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_products_from_shop_page' );
}
```

But it ends up removing everything including the products under categories.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you remove the main loop from the shop page template?

Comment: @disinfor Thank you. I tried removing the loop but I still get page numbers at the bottom as if products are there.

Comment: You should be able to remove all pagination and the main loop on the template. You might need to post more information.